# BeautifulSoup code Error

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-3.6

I cannot seem to find the problem in this code.
Help will be appreciated.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://nytimes.com'
r = requests.get(url)
r_html = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(r_html)

title = soup.find('span','articletitle').string
```

[Code & Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uvNq.png)

Comment: please paste some code instead of image. Then you must check the result of your query before trying to access any member

Comment: I've added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `http://nytimes.com` does not have any `articletitle` span. To be safe, just check `if soup.find('span','articletitle') is not None:` before accessing it. Also, you don't need to access `string` property here. For example, the following would work fine.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://nytimes.com'
r = requests.get(url)
r_html = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(r_html, 'html.parser')

if soup.find('div', 'suggestions') is not None:
    title = soup.find('div','suggestions')
    print(title)
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your code inside try and catch & then print exception which is occurring. using the exception occurred you can rectify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hi use a parser as your second argument for the get method,

Ex:-

```
page_content = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
```

Comment: What should page_response be??

Comment: Result set being null to would be another explanation.